# How to rescale data ranges in ERDAS?

Tags: erdas-imagine, stretch, spatial-modeler

I have an Normalized Difference Vegetation Index(NDVI) and Enhanced vegetation index (EVI) layer and I want to re-scale their data ranges to value ranges from 0–to–1, in order to optimally stretch the contrast (information contained in the image). I have analysed the histogram of the distribution of grey values and need to omit the lowest 0.5% and the highest 0.5% of the data, however I am not too sure how to go about doing this. I tried doing this in excel (manually deleting 0.5% min and 0.5% max values) and then completing the step in ERDAS model builder. The formula used in model builder (NDVI- new min)/(new max-new min), however my results were unsuccessful.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://hexagongeospatial.com/Community/forums/t/870.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Rescaling an NDVI or EVI from -1 to 1, to 0 to 1, uses the **Rescale** function (under **Raster**, **Radiometric**).

[image]

Clipping the top and bottom 0.5% is a percentage linear contrast stretch. To do this in ERDAS 2013, click on **Panchromatic**, then **General Contrast**. This brings up the **Contrast Adjust** window (seen below), and you can choose a variety of different methods of contrast adjustment.

You want to use **Percentage LUT** and set the % accordingly.

[image: Contrast Adjust Dialog Screenshot]

(I'm not sure of the specific steps in other versions unfortunately.)

Comment: Thank you for your respose, however Percentage LUT only changes the lookup table, the actual digital values do not change, and I am after finding a new minimum and maximum value (essentially by getting rid of 5% of the min values and 5% of the max values)

Comment: In that case, Rescale twice: once with "Clip to this range?" checked (to trim the tails, using desired min/max of your current range), then again to rescale to a 0-1 range.